# (Facebook) How to get user check-ins with FQL

Tags: facebook, stream, facebook-fql, facebook-checkins

I can get users check-ins with Graph API but not with FQL.

```
SELECT place FROM stream WHERE filter_key = 'owner' AND with_location = 'true' AND type = 285
```

Returns empty result.

```
SELECT message FROM checkin WHERE author_uid = me()
```

This returns very old check-ins which is like deprecated table.

How can I get FQL query to work with current users check-ins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that looks like Facebook deprecated checkin table and there are no new checkins here anymore. They started to use location_post table. So to get your checkins you may use

```
SELECT app_id, coords, author_uid, id, message, page_id, page_type, post_id, tagged_uids, timestamp, type FROM location_post WHERE author_uid = me()
```

Comment: Thank you it works! Do you know how I can get placename along with checkin privacy in a single query?

Comment: You may get it in multi query like this @"'query2':'SELECT coords, app_id, author_uid, id, message, page_id, page_type, post_id, tagged_uids, timestamp, type FROM location_post WHERE (author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) OR tagged_uids IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) OR tagged_uids = me()) AND timestamp > %li AND timestamp < %li',"

Comment: @"'query3':'select page_id, name, type, food_styles, hours, location, categories, "
                       "phone, pic, price_range, website, pic_big "
                       "from page where type in (\"RESTAURANT/CAFE\", \"BAR\", \"HOTEL\", \"LOCAL BUSINESS\") and page_id in (SELECT page_id, name, "
                       "type FROM place WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #query2)) ',"
                       @"}"

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is very close. If you want to avoid returning old check-ins, add a where clause for timestamp. For example, if I want to get check-ins for myself during the last 6 months (2678400 seconds in a month), I would do:

> SELECT author_uid, tagged_uids, target_id, coords, timestamp, message
>   FROM checkin WHERE author_uid = me() and timestamp > (now() -
>   (2678400*6))

If you want to grab checkins of friends, I would do:

> SELECT author_uid, tagged_uids, target_id, coords, timestamp, message
>   FROM checkin WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 =
>   me()) and timestamp > (now() - (2678400*6))

Comment: Thank you for your help but your query still returns old checkins :(